# "How many" vector fields are conservative?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

A vector field $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is conservative if for some "potential function" $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, we have $F=\nabla f$.

I am intuitively wondering "how many" vector fields are conservative. Obviously this can be interpreted in multiple ways, which is why I have multiple questions:

- if we define a "uniform" measure on the space of such vector fields $\mathcal F$ for say $n=2$, is the set of conservative vector fields then measured larger than $0$?
- can we put certain unrestrictive assumptions, or "natural" assumptions, on $F$ to ensure that they are conservative?
- how often do we encounter nonconservative vector fields in practice, e.g. in physics?

Comment: Given that we essentially compare smooth functions $\to \Bbb R$ with smooth functions $\to \Bbb R^n$, the conservative fields certainly form a zero-set

Answer (score 3):

In $\Bbb R^3$, $F$ must satisfy $\text{curl}\,F = 0$, and so this is three (closed) conditions on the space of vector fields. In higher dimensions, you convert the vector field $F$ to a $1$-form $\omega$ and it must satisfy $d\omega = 0$, which is again $\binom n2$ closed conditions. So you have closed conditions, which certainly define closed submanifolds (in the infinite dimensional function space). I'm not sure how you would put a measure on this space, though.

Thermodynamics is certainly full of path-dependent line integrals. Heat and work arise as non-exact $1$-forms, for example.

Comment: Hello Dr. Shifrin. I am reading your excellent book "Multivariable Mathematics", and I have a question about one of your statements regarding the equality of mixed partials. I was wondering if you could take a look? :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262481/why-should-the-equality-of-mixed-partials-be-intuitively-obvious