# Why should the equality of mixed partials be "intuitively obvious"?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am reading Ted Shifrin's excellent book *Multivariable Mathematics*. It claims that the equality of mixed partials is "an intuitively obvious result, but the proof is quite subtle". However, I guess I must be thinking in the wrong way, because I do not see the intuition behind this result. This is how I think about it:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. I think of $f_x$ as a "field of slopes" in the $x$-direction. If we analyze the movement in the $y$ direction in this field of slopes, we get $f_{xy}$. Now $f_y$ is a "field of slopes" in the $y$-direction. If we analyze movement in the $x$ direction here, we get $f_{yx}$.

It's unclear to me why movement in the $x$-direction in the "field of $y$-slopes" should be the same as movement in the $y$-direction in the "field of $x$-slopes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write the difference quotient for a small change $\Delta x$ in $x$ and then the difference quotient for that when you change $y$ by $\Delta y$ the result is the symmetric expression
$$\frac{
f(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y)
-f(x + \Delta x, y )
-f(   x, y + \Delta y)
+f(x,y)
}
{\Delta x \Delta y} .
$$

Comment: This is, of course, how the proof proceeds. So why do we need $C^2$ (or something slightly weaker) at all? :)

Comment: @TedShifrin You need some smoothness assumption to justify taking the limit in either order.

Answer (score 5):

I guess most people develop intuition based on examples, and most examples we pick to examine are $C^2$ functions, where the equality holds. Or, alternatively, you could say that the intuition comes from experience with Taylor's Theorem (which appears in Section 3 of Chapter 5 of my book). The intuition I guess I'm fondest of appears in Chapter 7 (exercise 19 of Section 2), just using a double integral and interchanging the order of integration. (After all, it's natural to think about $\displaystyle{\int\left(\int \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}dy\right)dx}$ and its companion.) I agree that it's not obvious a priori that the $y$ rate of change of $f_x$ should agree with the $x$ rate of change of $f_y$; the $C^2$ condition is subtle, as I said.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: I was hoping that you would respond to this question!